# Java complex validation in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, json, validation, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'd like to accept JSON on an REST endpoint and convert it to the correct type for immediate validation.

The endpoint looks like this:

```
@POST
public Response createCar(@Valid Car car) { 
    // persist to DB
    // ... 
}
```

But there are many subclasses of Car, e.g. Van, SelfDrivingCar, RaceCar, etc. How could I accept the different JSON representations on the endpoint, while keeping the validation code
in the Resource as concise as something like `@Valid Car car`?

Again: I send in JSON like (here, it's the representation of a subclass of Car, namely SelfDrivingCar):

```
{ 
    "id" : "t1",                      // every Car has an Id
    "kind" : "selfdriving",           // every Car has a type-hint
    "max_speed" : "200 mph",          // some attribute
    "ai_provider" : "fastcarsai ltd." // this is SelfDrivingCar-specific
}
```

and I'd like the validation machinery look into the `kind` attribute, create an instance of the appropriate subclass, here e.g. `SelfDrivingCar` and perform validation.

I know I could create different endpoints for all kind of cars, but thats does not seem DRY. And I know that I could use a real `Validator` instead of the annotation and do it by hand, so I'm just asking if there's some elegant shortcut for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the responsibility of your validation framework to extract the correct polymorphic type and validate it. Infact, by the time validation kicks in, the object *has already been created*. It can only work with what it has at that point. Note however that:

```
public Response createCar(@Valid Car car) {
    // ...
}
```

Will invoke validation on whatever the runtime type of 'car' actually is. So quite obviously what you want to do is assure that the `car` variable is bound at runtime to the correct type. This is the responsibility of your ***deserialization framework***. You will need to determine the correct way to do this with the JSON library being used in your application, but with Jackson you would have used the @JsonTypeInfo annotation to scope your polymorphic types.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.PROPERTY, property="kind")
public class Car implements Serializable {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track, found some article, too: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.de/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

Answer (score 1):

With DW 0.7.1

In my Case I have a custom User class and I there I add:

```
@ValidationMethod(message="user_name is null or empty")
public boolean isUserName() {       
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(user_name)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now the @Valid is used and I get an javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException in my tests --> @Test(expected=javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class)

Comment: What I don't like about both `@ValidationMethod` is that even if I put the validation logic in a different class, I sill have to pollute the Class being validated with a method tagged `@ValidationMethod`. Of course one can use `@Validated` with different validation groups but there is still pollution in the Class being validated.